# The second countdown to the event does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to correctly do several deductions to an event, but provide a separate identifier for days, minutes and seconds? Below I have only one countdown instead of two. How to improve it?

```
</head> 
    <?php $date = date('M d, Y H:i:s', strtotime('7-3-2019 15:37:25')); ?>
    <?php $date1 = date('M d, Y H:i:s', strtotime('8-3-2019 15:37:25')); ?>

    <script>
    var count = new Date("<?php echo $date;?>").getTime();
    var count1 = new Date("<?php echo $date1;?>").getTime();
    var x = setInterval( function(){ startTimer('demo',count); }, 1000 );
    var x = setInterval( function() { startTimer('demo1',count1); }, 1000 );
    function startTimer(id,countDownDate)
    {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = countDownDate - now;
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);    

        document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;

        if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }
    </script>

    <body>        
    <div id="demo"> 
     <p id="days"></p>
     <p id="hours"></p>
     <p id="minutes"></p>
     <p id="seconds"></p>
    </div>          
    <div id="demo1">
     <p id="days"></p>
     <p id="hours"></p>
     <p id="minutes"></p>
     <p id="seconds"></p>   
    </div>       
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are overwriting `x` fyi

Comment: What do you mean separate identifier for days, minutes and seconds?

Comment: As it is in the code, that's what I mean. The problem is that the second date is not displayed, the problem occurs in the JS script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version at end of answer.

> Below I have only one countdown instead of two. How to improve it?

Firstly, you are defining `x` twice in a row, thus overwriting it the second time. Without keeping track of your `setInterval()` calls, you can't clear them. When `clearInterval(x);` *does* get called, it will clear the second interval you created, but the first would continue to fire.

Because the intervals will be cleared *inside* the timers, you should store the interval inside the timers too. You'd then move the update logic to a new function (I called it `tick`), and you would use the timer functions with the `new` keyword.

> How to correctly do several deductions to an event, but provide a separate identifier for days, minutes and seconds.

Your HTML is almost right, actually. You would simply create tags for each one, and refer to them in your code.

But, you are re-using IDs in your HTML for `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`. You should only have 1 occurance of any ID in your HTML document.

Try using classes instead, and then, from the element whose ID is passed to `startTimer`, you can use [`Element.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) to get the divs you want.

## Working version of code:

```js
// These dates came from the PHP snippets in your post
var count = new Date("Mar 07, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();
var count1 = new Date("Mar 08, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();

var timer1 = new Timer('demo', count);
var timer2 = new Timer('demo1', count1);

function Timer(id, countDownDate) {
  this.interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var $elem = document.getElementById(id);

    $elem.getElementsByClassName("days")[0].innerHTML = 'days ' + days;
    $elem.getElementsByClassName("hours")[0].innerHTML = 'hours ' + hours;
    $elem.getElementsByClassName("minutes")[0].innerHTML = 'minutes ' + minutes;
    $elem.getElementsByClassName("seconds")[0].innerHTML = 'seconds ' + seconds;

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#demo,
#demo1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <h2>demo</h2>
  <p class="days"></p>
  <p class="hours"></p>
  <p class="minutes"></p>
  <p class="seconds"></p>
</div>
<div id="demo1">
  <h2>demo1</h2>
  <p class="days"></p>
  <p class="hours"></p>
  <p class="minutes"></p>
  <p class="seconds"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I added some extra stuff to make the preview clearer

Comment: Thank you very much :) I only have a question if this is not a problem. What should JS and PHP files look like, I want to move them to separate files So there would be three files: index.php, date.php (dates of events) and coundtowntimer.js I tried, but with a bad result

Comment: I can't speak for the dates with what I have in your post, but [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/c1gLfT2s4b8Znewoo5ns?p=preview) might show you a better idea of moving your JS out of your HTML

Comment: Can I ask for a lot of help? If so, as in this example, download the current time from the php server, not the local one. To count down from the server. I am already sitting this week and I can not do it. Please